# How to use Tailwind CSS with Yew?

Tags: rust, tailwind-css, yew, trunk-rs

I have tried to follow the steps described in https://dev.to/arctic_hen7/how-to-set-up-tailwind-css-with-yew-and-trunk-il9 to make use of Tailwind CSS in Yew, but it doesn't work.

My test project folder:

[image]

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "yew-tailwind-app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
yew = { version = "0.19" }
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link data-trunk href="./tailwind.css" rel="css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The codes in main.rs:

```rust
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
    html! {
        <>
            <h1>{ "Hello World" }</h1>
            <p class={ classes!("bg-red-500") }>{"Test!"}</p>
        </>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::start_app::<App>();
}
```

But I don't see the red background color in "Test!". Can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. did as it says here https://github.com/matiu2/tailwind-yew-builder . I took tailwind.css from the output directory and put it in the root of the project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Make use of Yew Tailwind builder indeed works. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think by far the cleanest solution is to use a trunk hook to build the CSS using the tailwind CLI. Something like is described here: https://www.matsimitsu.com/blog/2022-01-04-taliwind-cli-with-yew-and-trunk/

I personally installed the tailwind cli via yarn with a package.json (or npm if you prefer), but it's the same idea.

One benefit of this is the biggest benefit of tailwind: only the classes you need are included in the generated file.

Additionally, the use of the trunk hook means it's recompiled whenever trunk re-builds, including during development, and there's no unnecessary css files elsewhere in the project, it just uses the generated one.

Answer (score 4):

Tailwind CSS version 3.0 doesn't generate the full CSS by default anymore. This is why my codes didn't work when I made use of Tailwind CLI.

Follow the installation described in: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

And run it in the **watch** mode:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./output.css --watch
```

Alternative solution in the development mode: make use of Play CDN by adding the next script in the head tag of index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `tailwind.config.js` in your project root with the following contents. Modified from [Tailwind CSS doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation).

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,rs}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it still doesn't work.